# Why do I get “field.getSublistName is not a function” when setting a sublist value?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to transform a sales order to an item fulfillment using a SS 2.0 button event handler. As simple as possible. Not trying to do anything complicated. Surely something that has been done thousands of times before.

I get error "field.getSublistName is not a function" on the line after the todo:

```
var itemFulfillment = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    fromId: salesOrderId,
    toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
    isDynamic: true
});

var lineCount = itemFulfillment.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

log.debug({
    title: FUNCTION_NAME,
    details: {
        lineCount: lineCount
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

    itemFulfillment.selectLine({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: i
    });

    log.debug({
        title: FUNCTION_NAME,
        details: '1'
    });

    //todo error on next time: field.getSublistName is not a function

    itemFulfillment.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'itemreceive',
        value: true
    });

    log.debug({
        title: FUNCTION_NAME,
        details: '2'
    });

    itemFulfillment.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
}

log.debug({
    title: FUNCTION_NAME,
    details: '3'
});

const id = itemFulfillment.save();
```

If I try in non-dynamic mode then I get the same error:

```
var itemFulfillment = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    fromId: salesOrderId,
    toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT
});

var lineCount = itemFulfillment.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

log.debug({
    title: FUNCTION_NAME,
    details: {
        lineCount: lineCount
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

    log.debug({
        title: FUNCTION_NAME,
        details: '1'
    });

    //todo error on next time: field.getSublistName is not a function

    itemFulfillment.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: i,
        fieldId: 'itemreceive',
        value: true
    });

    log.debug({
        title: FUNCTION_NAME,
        details: '2'
    });
}

log.debug({
    title: FUNCTION_NAME,
    details: '3'
});

const id = itemFulfillment.save();
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I just received this today.

Comment: I think I reimplemented it as a Suitelet instead, called by the button, and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across getSublistName. If that's an error being thrown when you set the field value then I'd look for a client script (or a workflow) that runs when you set the field.

From the n/currentRecord module your options for like named functions are:

- getSublist
- getSublistField
- getSublistText
- getSublistValue

and of course the `getCurrentSublistxxx` variants.

What are you trying to do?

If there are no other scripts running (although since this also occurs in non-dynamic mode I'd suspect a workflow) then there may be something in NS that is throwing this. It may be that the sales order you are transforming isn't ready for fulfillment. It may also be that `itemreceive` is already set on the record. Whether to automatically include or exclude line items in a fulfillment is controlled at the account level. What happens when you create the itemfulfillment from the UI?

Comment: See first paragraph of question: "I'm trying to transform a sales order to an item fulfillment using a SS 2.0 button event handler. As simple as possible. Not trying to do anything complicated. Surely something that has been done thousands of times before."

Comment: @cja Is log.debug causing the issue? Ideally we include the title in inverted commas (' '). Just comment all the log.debugs and try once. Let me know.

Comment: @Finnick I added the logging because of the error. My question was specific about the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: So since your code is not calling `getSublistName ` then review my answer. I've added a bit more.

Comment: @cja did you figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and filed a defect, 690914 and they estimate it should be fixed in the next few weeks.